# How to merge few partials via templateUrl AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, merge, directive

I'm thinking is there a way to merge partial views via `templateUrl` in the `directive` in AngularJS?

Let's say I have directive:

```
.directive('mergeThisStupidPartials', function () {
    var mainpartial = "mainpartial.html",
    var template2 = "partial2.html",
    var template3 = "partial3.html"

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: mainpartial,

        //merge mainpartial with template2 and template3 
        //link function need?
    };
});
```

I will have few more partials and they will be renered in some conditions (for example:

*one view with mainpartial with partial2, partial4, partial6*

*another view with combined mainpartial with partial1 and partial5*)

I'm wondering this way, because my partials have a lot of HTML code, I can put them into `template` instead `templateUrl` but then there will be a huge block of code. I want to avoid that.

Is it possible in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `ng-include` all partials in `mainpartial.html`:

```
<div ng-include="template1"></div>
<div ng-include="template2"></div>
<div ng-include="template3"></div>
<!-- etc -->
```

Make sure to assign the partial urls to `$scope` variables:

```
.directive('mergeThisStupidPartials', function () {
    var mainpartial = "mainpartial.html";

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: mainpartial,
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.template1 = "partial1.html";
            $scope.template2 = "partial2.html";
            $scope.template3 = "partial3.html";
            // Etc
        }]
    };
}]);
```

You can also use the paths directly in `mainpartial.html`:

```
<div ng-include="'partial1.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'partial2.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'partial3.html'"></div>
```

Notice that I included extra quotes, so angular interprets the attributes as strings.

Comment: `$scope` in directive?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can inject $scope into directive, Angular throws me an error `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope`

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry, I wasn't paying attention. You'll need a controller in your directive to use the `$scope`... Fixed the answer.